# Как css-код сделать с отступами?

Tags: css, форматирование-кода

**Jinja** в коде **css** видит переменные. Когда начал **css-код** форматировать(ставить новые строки и табы), то **jinja** перестал видеть переменные.

Вопрос как бы решаем - взять и отформатировать **css-код** со всеми отступами и ошибка исчезнет, но там тысячи строк кода. Соответственно вручную это займет большое количество времени.

Могу, конечно написать скрипт на питоне, который отформатирует этот код, но прежде чем начать его делать хочу узнать есть ли уже такое решение?

Если да, то где, чтобы не писать свой обработчик текста. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ - попробуйте это. Если поможет отпишите потом, буду знать :)

Comment: Судя по вопросу, у вас либо css внутри html, либо вы зачем-то css через шаблонизатор прогоняете. Соответственно, нужно либо вынести css в отдельный файл, либо не прогонять его через шаблонизатор.

Comment: @insolor, css-код действительно в шаблоне был, т.к. код вставлялся из сторонних конструкторов. Поэтому я сначала действительно css-код вытаскивал в отдельный файл и тогда ошибка пропадала. Сейчас, конечно подумываю о скрипте, который будет парсить код и вытаскивать стили в отдельный файл, т.к. самому вытаскивать эти блоки - тоже так себе работа...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-общем, если кому понадобится вот мой обработчик:

```
with open('css.txt') as file:
   data = file.read()
new_data = ''

def add_tab(count_tab, _str_):
    for i in range(count_tab):
        _str_ += '\t'
    return _str_


count_tab = 0
for char in data:
    if char == '{':
        new_data += '\n'
        new_data = add_tab(count_tab, new_data)
        new_data += char
        new_data += '\n'
        count_tab += 1
        new_data = add_tab(count_tab, new_data)
        continue
    if char == ';':
        new_data += char
        new_data += '\n'
        new_data = add_tab(count_tab, new_data)
        continue
    if char == '}':
        new_data += '\n'
        count_tab -= 1
        new_data = add_tab(count_tab, new_data)
        new_data += char
        new_data += '\n'
        new_data = add_tab(count_tab, new_data)
        continue
    new_data += char
    
with open('new_css.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(new_data)
```

Comment: `css.txt` этого достаточно..

Comment: @De.Minov, я в курсе, что расширение файла д/б **.CSS**. Скрипт написан, чтобы вырезать из **project.CSS** и вставить в заготовленный **css.TXT** , а после работы скрипта скопировать из **new_css.TXT** и вставить обратно в **project.CSS**